# What was David doing to Walter?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

In **[Alien: Covenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant)**, there is a scene I couldn't really understand.

There is a fight scene between David and Walter, right after they kiss. During this scene, David seems to stab Walter and rip something out of Walter's throat, a long object that he keeps in his hand for a second.

***What exactly happens during this scene?***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

David stabbed Walter in the neck with the wind instrument that they were playing earlier. The thing David is holding immediately afterwards is not something that he ripped out of Walter, it's just the wind instrument, which he pulled out of Walter's neck after the stab.